# How to show google map marker after x seconds without refresh google map?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3

How to display google map after every x seconds without google map refresh?

1.Markers latLong are coming from database.

2.Allocate that markers on google map.

3.Markers's latLong changes after 30 second.

Problem is google map get refreshed. All I want google map should display without refresh with updated LatLong.

Here is my code.

```
<script>

    function initMap() {
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 12,
            center: {lat: 19.9518684, lng: 73.7354084}
        });

        var image = '<?php echo $getImagePath; ?>'
        for (var o in markers) {

            lat = markers[ o ].lat;
            lng = markers[ o ].lng;
            address = markers[ o ].address;

            var my = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            //console.log(my);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: my,
                map: map,
                icon: image,

            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.setContent("'" + address + "'");
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });

        }

    }

</script>
```

I tried `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);` and `window.onload = initMap;` but didn't work.

Can any one help me out?

Comment: don't do `for (var o in markers){` in `function initMap() {`

Comment: markers is an array so i have to do this

Comment: to be honest, I can't see with your code how the markers could update at all, let alone every 30 seconds

Comment: I meant, don't do that in initMap, not don't do that at all

Comment: can you show how you handle changing marker positions now?

Comment: I am using setInterval(function()
 {
  $("#refreshButton").click();
 }, 30000); function

Comment: refreshButton is hidden and i am using yii2 + PJax

Comment: oh, so you're reloading the page every 30 seconds ... well, you'll have to rethink how you get your new marker positions (use AJAX) - really, it's not that `google map get refreshed` it's that the whole page is refreshed? is it? (no idea what `$("#refreshButton").click()` actually does, as you have not shown that either)

Comment: no whole page not get refreshed. only google map get refreshed

Comment: really, so what code does clicking `$("#refreshButton")` run? you haven't shared that important piece of information

Comment: here's some marker methods that may help ... `marker.setPosition(LatLng)` and `marker.setMap(null);` - this allows you to move or remove a marker - what would help is knowing the code that downloads the updated marker position

Answer (score 0):

I hope this small rewrite of your code will help you on your way. As it stands, there's a lot of information not present in the question, so I can only guess

```
// note these are globals because they are set in initMap and used outside of it
var image = '<?php echo $getImagePath; ?>';
var map;
var infowindow;
var markers = [/* some initially loaded markers loaded as if by majick unicorn farts */];

function initMap() {
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: {lat: 19.9518684, lng: 73.7354084}
    });
    doMarkers(true);
}
function doMarkers(firstLoad) {
    markers.forEach(marker => {
        var lat = marker.lat;
        var lng = marker.lng;

        marker.my = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

        if (firstLoad) { // marker has no marker the first time because it's not on a map yet
            marker.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: marker.my,
                map: map,
                icon: image,

            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker.marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.setContent("'" + marker.address + "'");
                infowindow.open(map, marker.marker);
            });
        } else { // move existing marker
            marker.marker.setPosition(marker.my);
        }
    }
}
function magicallyFindAndUpdateMarkerDataUsingUnicornFarts(marker) {
    // find corresponding marker in markers array
    // update lat, lng and address
}
function doSomeAjaxToGetNewMarkerPositionsAndCallCallback(cb) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'someURI');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        data.forEach(function(marker) {
           magicallyFindAndUpdateMarkerDataUsingUnicornFarts(marker); 
        });
        cb()
    }
    xhr.send();
}
setInterval(function () {
    doSomeAjaxToGetNewMarkerPositionsAndCallCallback(function() {
        doMarkers(false);
    });
}, 30000);
```

Of course, I can't see how markers are loaded (into `markers` in your code), nor can I tell you what `doSomeAjaxToGetNewMarkerPositionsAndCallCallback` or `magicallyFindAndUpdateMarkerDataUsingUnicornFarts` should be, because you haven't shown any code regarding markers at all

Comment: Thank you for your help. Let me try this.